# Magento - remove shipping method

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with removing shipping method in magento. I read a few tutorials but it sill doesn't work. When I made changes in core file everything works well but I want to override the files according to best practices.

I thnink it's probably problem with config.xml.

My extension:

```
CompanyName/
  ExtensionName/
     Block/
       Onepage/
          Abstract.php
     controllers/
       OnepageController.php
     etc/
       config.xml
     Model/
       Type/
          Onepage.php
```

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_ExtensionName>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </CompanyName_ExtensionName>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage>CompanyName_ExtensionName_Block_Onepage</onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <checkout>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <CompanyName_ExtensionName before="Mage_Checkout">
                                CompanyName_ExtensionName
                            </CompanyName_ExtensionName>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </checkout>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
        <models>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <type_onepage>CompanyName_ExtensionName_Model_Type_Onepage</type_onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
            </models>
        </global>
</config>
```

**/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php**

```
abstract class CompanyName_ExtensionName_Onepage_Abstract extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
{

    protected function _getStepCodes()
    {
        return array('login','billing', 'payment', 'review');
    }
}
```

**/controllers/OnepageController.php**

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class CompanyName_ExtensionName_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    protected $_sectionUpdateFunctions = array(
        'payment-method' => '_getPaymentMethodsHtml',
        'review' => '_getReviewHtml',
    );

    public function saveBillingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
        $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);
        if (isset($data['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
        }
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);
        if (!isset($result['error'])) {
            /* check quote for virtual */
            if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                );
            } else {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }

    public function saveShippingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_address_id', false);
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
                );
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
}
```

**/Model/Type/Onepage.php**

```
    class CompanyName_ExtensionName_Model_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
    {

        public function saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
        {


   if (empty($shippingMethod)) {
            $shippingMethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
        }
        $rate = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod);
        if (!$rate) {
            return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
        }
        $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
            ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);

        $this->getCheckout()
            ->setStepData('shipping_method', 'complete', true)
            ->setStepData('payment', 'allow', true);

        return array();
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to overwrite the block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract`. For this block, rewrite code inside `config.xml`  should look like below.

```
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_abstract>CompanyName_ExtensionName_Block_Onepage_Abstract</onepage_abstract>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
```

And you should extend the above mentioned block at `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Onepage_Abstract extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract {

     //rewrite code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your purpose is to remove Checkout page: #3 Shipping Information and #4 Shipping Method then follow these steps:

Set: Product Type as: Virtual Product. This will turn-off #3 Shipping Information & #4 Shipping Method.

Checkout Process will become:
1. Checkout Method
2. Billing Information
3. Payment Information
4. Order Review

Works on Version 1.7 - 1.9 CE

Read Magento Knowledge Base: Understanding Product Types:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/product-types